# How to only get the error rows while inserting into oracle using pandas.to_sql()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, oracle, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which is having 10 rows out which 2 rows are already in the oracle table.

So I want to capture these 2 rows which will cause an error (oracle.Integrity) while it should enter the rest of the 8 rows.

I can achieve that while inserting rows in chunk of size 1. But If I have a dataframe of more than 100k rows and Lets say I am using a chunk size of 10k, then even if any one row fails for any reason, it marks the entire chunk of rows the same reason.

Is there any way I can get the error rows from the chunk.

Currently I am using below code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# create a database connection
engine = create_engine('oracle://user:password@host:port/service_name')

# define the table name and the DataFrame with new data
table_name = 'my_table'
new_data = pd.DataFrame({...})

# insert the data in chunks and capture the rows that failed to insert
failed_rows = []
chunk_size = 1000

for i in range(0, len(new_data), chunk_size):
   chunk = new_data.iloc[i:i+chunk_size]
try:
    chunk.to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=chunk_size)
except Exception as e:
    failed_chunk = chunk.copy()
    failed_chunk['failed_reason'] = str(e)
    failed_rows.append(failed_chunk)

# concatenate the failed rows into a single DataFrame
if failed_rows:
    failed_data = pd.concat(failed_rows)
    print(f'These rows failed to insert: {failed_data}')
```

The code above will capture the all the rows in that chunk even if a single row cause error. How can I only get the rows which is not inserted in the database ?

Comment: Drop down to the native driver and use `executemany()` with the `batcherrors` option: https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html#handling-data-errors This will allow valid data be inserted, and let you identify invalid data.

Comment: You need to use upsert operation I believe. AFAIK "merge into" statement works for Oracle. Maybe this question will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72022076/upsert-in-oracle-using-python-pandas

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of using `executemany()` with `batcherrors()` to get the invalid data.

```
"""

drop table t purge;
create table t as select * from dept where 1 = 0;
alter table t add constraint t_pk primary key (deptno);

"""

import os
import sys

import oracledb
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError

# Let SQLAlchemy 1.4 use the newest Oracle driver
oracledb.version = "8.3.0"
sys.modules["cx_Oracle"] = oracledb

un = os.environ.get("PYTHON_USERNAME")
pw = os.environ.get("PYTHON_PASSWORD")
cs = os.environ.get("PYTHON_CONNECTSTRING")  # localhost/orclpdb1 format
hostname, service_name = cs.split("/")


try:

    engine = create_engine(f'oracle://{un}:{pw}@{hostname}/?service_name={service_name}')

    # Get some data
    sql = "select * from dept"
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, engine)

    print("The dataframe:")
    print(df)

    # Naive conversion to a format for executemany()
    bnd = []
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        bnd.append((row[0], row[1], row[2]))

    # Add a bad value with a duplicate key
    bnd.append((10, "dummy", "dummy"))

    #print(bnd)

    # Get the oracledb driver connection
    dbapi_conn = engine.raw_connection()
    with dbapi_conn.cursor() as cursor:

        # Insert data into target table
        cursor.executemany("insert into t (deptno, dname, loc) values (:1, :2, :3)", bnd, batcherrors=True)

        print("\nThe data values that couldn't be inserted:")
        for error in cursor.getbatcherrors():
            print(f"Error {error.message} at row offset {error.offset}. Bad data is {bnd[error.offset]}")

        print("\nThe rows that were inserted:")
        sql = "select * from t"
        for r in cursor.execute(sql):
            print(r)

except SQLAlchemyError as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: I did run the this, it executed successfully, but I can't see any data on the table. 

I am using **df.values.tolist()** in place of **bnd**. Is this correct ? or Do I also need to use autocommit()

Comment: Try what I showed and then vary it.  Autocommit is not relevant - in fact it is ignored if there are data errors; see the user documentation.